# How to inject EJB into SOAPHandler?

Tags: ejb, jax-ws, cdi

My JAX-WS war contains following entries.

```
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/beans.xml // empty
WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/corrs-beans-1.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT.jar // EJBs are here
WEB-INF/lib/corrs-entities-1.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-1.6.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/opensaml-2.5.1-1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/openws-1.4.2-1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/wss4j-1.6.8.jar
WEB-INF/lib/xmlsec-1.5.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/xmltooling-1.3.2-1.jar
WEB-INF/web.xml
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/kr.co.ticomms.corrs/
META-INF/maven/kr.co.ticomms.corrs/corrs-services/
META-INF/maven/kr.co.ticomms.corrs/corrs-services/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/kr.co.ticomms.corrs/corrs-services/pom.properties
```

One of my SOAPHandlers trying to call EJB.

```java
@HandlerChain(file=...)
@WebService(...)
public class MyService {
}

public class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context) {
        // MyEJB null
    }

    @Inject
    private MyEJB myEJB; // << NULL
}
```

MyEJB is just an nointerface-view EJB.

```java
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how to inject EJBs into SOAPHandlers?

**UPDATE / (maybe)ANSWER**

I changed `@Inject` to `@EJB` and it works.

Is there any way to work with `@Inject`? I looks IMHO better. :)

Comment: How do you bind the handler to the web service? _The specification only mentions support for [`@Resource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation injection in the handler lifecycle._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `SOAPHandler`s are invoked before the web service invocation. According to the CDI spec (see [scopes and contexts](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#contexts)), in a web services context all the normal scopes are *only* active during the web service invocation. In addition to all the normal scopes, there is also the `@Dependent` pseudo scope. Unless otherwise specified, this is the default scope. It's life cycle depends on one of the normal scopes and as such cannot exist by itself.

Now, a stateless EJB since it has no CDI related annotations, it is automatically `@Dependent` and cannot be injected (using `@Inject`) anywhere a normal scope is not active. In your case, inside a `SOAPHandler` there is no scope active so you cannot use `@Inject`.

Use `@EJB`, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you annotate your soap handler class with CDI "@named" annotation, you can inject any EJB component. By doing so, your soap handler class becomes a container managed bean and you start to be able to use other container managed beans as EJBs.

```java
@Named

public class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler'<'SOAPMessageContext'>' {

....

@Inject

private MyEJB myEJB; 

...

}
```

Comment: Using Glassfish/Payara I'll get a NullPointerException at least when trying to inject a normal CDI Bean (non EJB).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else google here like I did, it's possible to do that in TomEE: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/trunk/server/openejb-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/openejb/server/cxf/handler/SimpleHandler.java